# How would you say "Teaching Assistant"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence

> Li laboras kiel  en la universitato.

**Instruado-helpanto** does not look natural to me.
**subprelegonto** looks more native but is long.

Is it a good translation? Are there any other options?

Dankon!

Answer (score 2):

[*Oficiala aldono 8*](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/aktoj/aktoj2/8oa.html) lists the verb *asisti* for which [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#asisti_kd) gives the derivative *asistanto* with a Zamenhofian example *Li ricevis la oficon de asistanto ĉe la profesoro.*

When I studied at university all assistants were just assistants, whether they held exercises or assisted in research, most did both. So *asistanto* should be enough in most cases. If you need to specify that a certain assistant helps only at teaching, I would say *asistanto pri instruado* after the example *profesoro pri retoriko* in [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#pri_kd).

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm a teaching assistant myself, as part of my job as a "Wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter" (scientific employee) at a university of applied sciences. I don't know whether any official term exists for that kind of position in Esperanto, but when I talk about that aspect of my job in Esperanto, I usually use the term "instruist-helpanto" (teacher's helper), as the main responsibility for the course rests with the lecturer, but I'm tasked with helping them by preparing some of the teaching material, guiding exercise lessons, giving feedback on the lectures etc.

> **Instruado-helpanto** does not look natural to me.

You don't really need the "-ad·" suffix in there, as the focus on duration doesn't really affect the "helping" with the task. *Instru(-)helpanto* or *instruo(-)helpanto* are thus sufficient to express almost the same.

> **subprelegonto** looks more native but is long.

"-ont·" is the suffix for a *future* active participle. You'd probably want "-ant·" for someone who actually holds (and works in) a position, rather than just being designated for it. I'd expect a *subpreleganto* to actually hold either a part of a course's lectures or even all of them (under the supervision of the official lecturer), which a teaching assistant wouldn't necessarily have to do. (Of course this can depend on the school / university and even on the individual course.) So while this might be a good term for teaching assistants actually tasked with holding lectures, I don't think it can be used as a general translation of "teaching assistant".

Comment: Very clear explanations! Dankon